# RightLight technology in Logitech webcams

Tags: webcam, directshow, logitech

I note one feature for Logitech webcams -  if the RightLight option is turned on in the webcam properties,  then  output frame rate decreases in two times (1920x1080 with 30 fps -> ~15 fps) for rendering.   For test I used  DirectShow and the Logitech webcams: c270, c310 and c920.

Any ideas -  how to force a webcam to work with 30 fps with RightLight?

Comment: Webcams are - in general - known for reduced frame rates in low light conditions. It is not exactly the class of devices to operate at fixed frame rate. I think RightLight is more of a marketing buzzword here.

Comment: You are right, if a webcam doesn't have enough power for frames handling in RightLight, then the webcam begins to skip frames. The webcams are not those devices for precision video. RightLight is only a business solution. Thank for help, Roman.

Answer (score 0):

RightLight halves the framerate as part of how it functions. You are better off adding another light and turning off Rightlight.